# How to configure the Oracle 19c database connectionstring in ODBC Linked service in Azure Data Factory

Tags: odbc, azure-data-factory, oracle19c, linked-service

We want to connect to an Oracle 19c database on ssl connection using ODBC Linked service.

When we configure DSN on the SHIR machine - we give "DSN=oracle_service_name" in the ConnectionString field while configuring the linked service and these are backed by full oracle client on SHIR machine having a TNSNAMES.ora and SQLNET.ora files

In SQLNET.ora file - we specify an Oracle wallet  that contains the certificates for the SSL enablement.

We want to use Azure Key Vault to store the entire connectionstring for the ODBC linked service and want to ensure we don't need TNSNAMES.ora and SQLNET.ora and want to embed all the info in the connectionstring itself.

How can we construct this ODBC connectionstring ?